# Kong 3.1 on Kubernetes on Anthos - Kong Manager is not loading

Tags: kong, kong-ingress

We have installed Kong enterprise 3.1 in Anthos (GKE). Installation is succesfull. All services are running fine. When we try to access kong manager, it is loading only "Kong Admin" header....
When I debug in chrome browser, it shows "Failed to load Resource: status 404(), kconfig.jsp "...Any help on this.